# Find $x$ if $\cos(x)={1+\sqrt3\over 2\sqrt2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find $x$ if

$$\cos(x)={1+\sqrt3\over 2\sqrt2}$$

Thanks a bunch, I just don't know which identity to use

Comment: Are you familiar with the arccosine (also called the inverse cosine) function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
\cos2x&=2\cos^2x-1\\
&=2\cdot\frac{1+3+2\sqrt{3}}{8}-1\\
&=\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2}-1\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: .. nice answer +1

Answer (score 2):

HINT : 
$$\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{2\sqrt 2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$
with $\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta$.